# Keras cross-validation accuracy settling at (1/output_classes) after each epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-2

I am currently trying to train a DNN for speech recognition with large number of speakers, each having their own label (output_classes = Total number of speakers).
My database right now has 300 speakers and the Keras model summary is as follows:

> 1240 (input size) --> 256 hidden --> 256 hidden --> 256 hidden (0.5 dropout) --> 256 (0.5 dropout) --> Softmax (300)

I am feeding the data in batches (each speaker data = one batch) and using the following optimizer:

```
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='Adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and `fit_generator` as follows:

```
model.fit_generator(
    trainGen(i=0),
    steps_per_epoch=num_class,
    epochs=500,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

where `trainGen` is my generator function

While training, the cross-validation accuracy always settles to 0.0033 i.e. 1/300. The training and cross-validation losses are falling after each epoch though.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You are most probably overfitting. How many datapoints do you have?

Comment: I am feeding frame level log-filter bank features to the network. On average there are about 2000 feature frames for each speaker. I suspect overfitting too, but regularization has not helped much.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out my network was overfitting massively as my database was too small. Adding more data and regularization finally helped in getting a decent accuracy.